# Voting to reroll a message in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, chatbot

I'm pretty new to programming and discord.js in general, so I used a command handler from a guide. I am trying to create a bot that when you do !spin it gives you a game from a `gameList` array I made. That works as intended and gets sent out in a rich embed.

I wanted to make it so if the group wasn't satisfied with that game they could reroll it with a vote of at least 3. To do that I tried using reactions to the message but couldn't get anything to really work.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'spin',
  description: 'Spins the wheel!',
  execute(message) {
    const gameList = ['Games inside array'];
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameList.length);
    var games = gameList[x];

    const voteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#F8AA2A')
      .setTitle('Game Spinner')
      .addField(games, ' was the chosen game!');

    message.channel.send(voteEmbed).then((voteEmbed) => {
      voteEmbed.react('');
    });

    var noCount = 0;

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return [``].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
    };

    const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 10000 });
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
      if (reaction.emoji.name === ``) {
        noCount += 1;
      }
    });

    collector.on('end', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
      if (noCount >= 3) {
        message.channel.send(voteEmbed).then((voteEmbed) => {
          voteEmbed.react('');
        });
      }
    });
  },
};
```

No errors show up, it just never sends the new `voteEmbed` after three votes have been hit. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is located here: `const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 10000});`

You are creating a reaction collector on the message received by the end when you want to listen to reactions to the message sent.

You need to replace your code by something like:

The main edit is to change the reactionCollector to listen to the voteEmbed message ^

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
  name: "spin",
  description: "Spins the wheel!",
  execute(message) {
    const gameList = [Games inside array]
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameList.length);
        var games = gameList[x];

        const voteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#F8AA2A")
        .setTitle("Game Spinner")
        .addField(games, " was the chosen game!");


        message.channel.send(voteEmbed).then(voteEmbed => {
            voteEmbed.react('')

            var noCount = 0;
            
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return [``].includes(reaction.emoji.name);

            const collector = voteEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 10000});
            collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === ``) {
                    noCount+=1
                }
            });

            collector.on('end', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                if (noCount >= 3){
                    message.channel.send(voteEmbed).then(voteEmbed => {
                        voteEmbed.react('')
                    })
                 }
            });
        })
      };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the code given above and I didn't get any errors still but after reaching the required amount of votes it won't resend a new voteEmbed. If you have any ideas about why it isn't working I'm all ears.